# How to add memory to load_qa_chain or How to implement ConversationalRetrievalChain with custom prompt with multiple inputs

Tags: openai-api, langchain, py-langchain, large-language-model, openaiembeddings

I am trying to provide a custom prompt for doing Q&A in langchain. I wasn't able to do that with ConversationalRetrievalChain as it was not allowing for multiple custom inputs in custom prompt. Hence, I used load_qa_chain but with load_qa_chain, I am unable to use memory.

How to add memory to load_qa_chain or  How to implement ConversationalRetrievalChain with custom prompt with multiple inputs.

```py
    import openai
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import os
    from langchain.embeddings.openai import OpenAIEmbeddings
    from langchain.vectorstores import Chroma
    from langchain.text_splitter import RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter
    from langchain.llms import OpenAI
    from langchain.chains import RetrievalQA, ConversationalRetrievalChain,RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain
    from langchain.chains.qa_with_sources import load_qa_with_sources_chain
    from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain
    from langchain.document_loaders import UnstructuredFileLoader
    from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
    
    from langchain.document_loaders import UnstructuredExcelLoader
    loader = UnstructuredFileLoader("../document.pdf", mode="elements")
    documents = loader.load()
    text_splitter = RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=0)
    texts = text_splitter.split_documents(documents)
    #embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings()
    from langchain.embeddings.sentence_transformer import SentenceTransformerEmbeddings
    embeddings = SentenceTransformerEmbeddings(model_name="all-MiniLM-L6-v2")
    vectorDB = Chroma.from_documents(texts,embeddings)
    
    
    prompt_template = "You are a Chat customer support agent.\
            Address the customer as Dear Mr. or Miss. depending on customer's gender followed by Customer's First Name.\
            Use the following pieces of context to answer the question at the end.\
            If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer.\
            Below are the details of the customer:\
            Customer's Name : {Customer_Name} \
            Customer's Resident State: {Customer_State}\
            Customer's Gender: {Customer_Gender}\
            {context}\
            Question: {question}\
            Answer: "
    
    import json
     
    # Opening JSON file
    with open('Customer_profile.json', 'r') as openfile:
    # Reading from json file
        json_object = json.load(openfile)
     
    cName=json_object['Customer_Name']
    cState=json_object['Customer_State']
    cGen=json_object['Customer_Gender']
    
    PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
        template=prompt_template, input_variables=["context", "question","Customer_Name","Customer_State","Customer_Gender"]
    )
    
    chain_type_kwargs = {"prompt": PROMPT}
    
    from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
    memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", output_key='answer',return_messages=True)
    
    #qa = RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain.from_chain_type(OpenAI(temperature=0), retriever=vectorDB.as_retriever(),chain_type="stuff", memory=memory,return_source_documents=True,chain_type_kwargs=chain_type_kwargs)
    #qa = RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain.from_chain_type(OpenAI(temperature=0), retriever=vectorDB.as_retriever(),chain_type="stuff", memory=memory,return_source_documents=True)
    #qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(OpenAI(temperature=0), retriever=vectorDB.as_retriever(),chain_type="stuff", memory=memory,return_source_documents=True,chain_type_kwargs=chain_type_kwargs)
    #qa = load_qa_with_sources_chain(OpenAI(temperature=0),chain_type="stuff",prompt=PROMPT)
    qa = load_qa_chain(OpenAI(temperature=0.1),chain_type="stuff",prompt=PROMPT)
    
    import langchain
    langchain.debug=False
    query="How's the weather in my place?"
    docs = vectorDB.similarity_search(query)
    
    
    
    #vectordbkwargs = {"search_distance": 0.9}
    #result=qa({"input_documents": docs,"question": query,'Customer_Gender':'Male','Customer_State':'Madhya Pradesh','Customer_Name':'Bob'})
    result=qa({"input_documents": docs,"question": query,'Customer_Gender':'Male','Customer_State':'Madhya Pradesh','Customer_Name':'Bob'})
    #result=qa({"question": query})
    print(result['output_text'])
```

**Customer Profile.JSON**

```json
    {
        "Customer_Name": "Bob",
        "Customer_State": "NY",
        "Customer_Gender": "Male"
    }
```

Comment: share some samples from  `Customer_profile.json` , this will help to debug and recreate it.

Comment: @simpleApp Updated the question and included Customer_profile.json

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't store memory in load_qa_chain function, since it accepts docs and input question, rather you need to store the response of previous question in local cache and pass it to the prompt each time. The next one conversationRetrievalChain helps here by doing it for you.

You can use the condense_question_prompt parameter while initializing the ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm()..

You can define prompt like this

```
def get_new_prompt():
    custom_template = """Given the following conversation and a follow up question, 
    rephrase the follow up question to be a standalone question. At the end of standalone question 
    add this 'Do not answer the question based on you own knowledge.' If you do not know the answer 
    reply with 'I am sorry'.
    Chat History:
    {chat_history}
    Follow Up Input: {question}
    Standalone question:"""
    CUSTOM_QUESTION_PROMPT = PromptTemplate.from_template(custom_template)
    return CUSTOM_QUESTION_PROMPT
```

and the models could be

```
retriever = vector_store.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'k': 1})
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(return_messages=True, memory_key='chat_history', human_prefix = 'Human', ai_prefix= 'AI')
chat = ChatOpenAI(model=LLM, openai_api_key=OPENAPI_TOKEN, temperature=0, max_tokens=100)

conv_chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(chat, condense_question_prompt=get_new_prompt(), retriever=retriever,memory=memory)
```

Try this one!

you may need to use session cache or mem cache to store the memory after each run and for the next api call(question) use the cache to create new chain from the existing memory.

Answer (score -1):

Based on my custom PDF, you can have the following logic:
you can refer my [notebook](https://github.com/simpleappdesigner/LangChain_101/blob/main/LangChain_101_memory.ipynb) for more detail.

```
# doc string prompt
#
prompt_template = """You are a Chat customer support agent.\
        Address the customer as Dear Mr. or Miss. depending on customer's gender followed by Customer's First Name.\
        Use the following pieces of context to answer the question at the end.\
        If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer.\
        Below are the details of the customer:\
        Customer's Name : {Customer_Name} \
        Customer's Resident State: {Customer_State}\
        Customer's Gender: {Customer_Gender}\
        {context}\
        Question: {question}\
        Answer: """
PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
    template=prompt_template, input_variables=["context", "question","Customer_Name","Customer_State","Customer_Gender"]
)
from langchain.chains.question_answering import load_qa_chain

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", input_key="question")
chain = load_qa_chain(
    OpenAI(temperature=0), chain_type="stuff", memory=memory, prompt=PROMPT
)


query="why frog sent letter to Todd??"
docs=db.similarity_search(query=query)

# building the dictionary for chain

chain_input={
    "input_documents": docs,
    "context":"This is contextless",
    "question":query,
    "Customer_Name":"Bob",
    "Customer_State":"NY",
    "Customer_Gender":"Male"
}

result=chain(chain_input, return_only_outputs=True)
```

output:

```
 Dear Mr. Bob, Frog sent a letter to Toad because he wanted to show Toad that he was glad to be his best friend. He wrote in the letter, "Dear Toad, I am glad that you are my best friend. Your best friend, Frog."'
```

if you are planning to have a chat history, can use `memory`.

Comment: This won't work, you need to edit your `prompt_template` to have a `chat_history` input_variable. https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/memory/adding_memory_chain_multiple_inputs#:~:text=memory%20import%20ConversationBufferMemory-,API%20Reference%3A,-load_qa_chain%20from%20langchain

Comment: you can refer to the notebook attached to the answer where you can see the complete example.